# Filetype shortcuts in vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I added 4 following lines to my vimrc file to add shortcuts (to run current *.html buffer in browser and to run current *.js file in node):

```
autocmd filetype html map <C-S-F10> :sav %<CR>:! chromium-browser %<Enter>
autocmd filetype html inoremap <C-S-F10> <Esc>:sav %<CR>:! chromium-browser %<Enter>
autocmd filetype javascript map <C-S-F10> :sav %<CR>:! node %<Enter>
autocmd filetype javascript inoremap <C-S-F10> <Esc>:sav %<CR>:! node %<Enter>
```

It works fine when I have only html files or only JavaScript files open. But when I have any combination of these file types open in different buffers (using tabs) and want to open HTML file in browser and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> my HTML file goes to Node, which throws compilation error.

**Progress:**

When I type `:set filetype` it says `html` for *.html and `javascript` for *.js files. So the problem is not in improper file type.

I tried to set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> shortcut for opening in browser and that somehow solves my problem. Now, when both filetypes plus files without filetype are open at the same time I can open any (html, js and plain text) filetype in browser with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and send it to Node to compile with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. Why it happens?

Here my [vimrc](http://hastebin.com/obacesaziz.xml) file. Vim version is 7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off adding filetype plugins to the after section of your user vim runtime directory, and defining your mappings there without using `autocmd`.

For example, in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim` you would put your HTML mappings, and `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` for JavaScript mappings.

However, that won't solve your problem. You need to make your mappings buffer-local. Try this, for HTML buffers:

```
map <buffer> <C-S-F10> :sav %<CR>:! chromium-browser %<Enter>
inoremap <buffer> <C-S-F10> <Esc>:sav %<CR>:! chromium-browser %<Enter>
```

And this, for JavaScript buffers:

```
map <buffer> <C-S-F10> :sav %<CR>:! node %<Enter>
inoremap <buffer> <C-S-F10> <Esc>:sav %<CR>:! node %<Enter>
```

See:

```
:help :map-local
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. "You're better off adding filetype plugins to the after section of your user vim runtime directory" - what advantages except not bloating vimrc file it gives? I thought that it kind of more convenient to have all my configuration in one place.

Comment: Mainly you know for sure that your mappings will be defined after all the system stuff has been sourced, so yours can override the system stuff where necessary.  If you use an autocmd there's no guarantee it will happen in that order (and, in fact, probably won't).

Comment: Thank you, that is a working solution! It has the small downside of having to define a file for each filetype and repeating code in there. Before you could concat `javascript,json,etc...` in the autocmd line.

Comment: @atripes You could make each file :source a common file.